# Human readable optimised version of C/C++ line

Tags: c++, c, gcc, optimization

I have a long C++ line of ORs and ANDs chained together. Of course, the compiler is much better than me at optimising it, and I shouldn't try to oversmart it. But, for learning purposes, I would like to know if the expression can be optimised, and how is the compiler seeing it after passing with `-O3` and `-Os`.

Is there a way to do this? I can just extract the expressions I want one by one and put them in a new program.

As a silly example, if I have:

```
if( n < 2 && n < 1 )
```

I want to see that the compiler has seen that it can be simplified to:

```
if ( n < 1 )
```

**Edit:**
Other cases where optimisation magic can occur involve byte shifting, for example in division by powers of 2.

A real example is this:

```
if(((col1 < col2) && (col1 + pdim < col2))
    || ((col2 < col1) && (col2 + pdim < col1))
    || ((row1 < row2) && (row1 + pdim < row2))
    || ((row2 < row1) && (row2 + pdim < row1))){
    overlap = false;
}
```

This piece of code checks if two squares of size `pdim` defined by the coordinates of the upper left corner `(col1, row1)`, `(col2, row2)` are overlapping.

This is mostly to learn what the compiler can do for itself, not to use it in production. Of course, writing the optimised version of the C line myself is a bad idea, as it will just hurt readability, and only save a few microseconds in compiling time. But there are scenarios where it could turn useful, for example, when writing in Python, where there is no compiler an Cython is not an option, having access to an optimised version may be useful.

I am currently using GCC on Linux, but could do the same thing with Clang or any other alternative, if it were more convenient.

Comment: You can use a decompiler on the result...

Comment: @MooingDuck: I think he means is there a way to see if the compiler discovers redundancies in my expression that I fail to see.To which the answer is (to my knowledge) 'no'.

Comment: He can try to read the disassembly and see what the compiler does with his lines of code, but thats kinda hard..

Comment: You don't even need to, assuming you are using gcc you can get the assembler output using the `-S` flag. IIRC the output was annotated.

Comment: There is a way that is used in digital logic called a Karnaugh map http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map.  Using this you can reduce a huge expression into something very simple.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Those are very useful for boolean algebra, but as far as boolean algebra is concerned, the expressions in in the question (and many other conditions that can be simplified) are just `p * q` and `q` with no further information about `p` and `q`. To prove these equivalent, one has to prove things like `p = q` or `p = 1` which is outside the domain of boolean algebra (and hence Karnaugh maps).

Comment: I have expanded the question a bit adding examples and applications. I hope it makes it clearer. Please, do tell me if more is required, or if there is another flavour of Stack Exchange more appropiate for it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

GCC's optimization passes work on an intermediary representation of your code in a format called [GIMPLE](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GIMPLE).

Using the [-fdump-* options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html), you can ask GCC to output intermediary states of the tree.

E.g.

test.cc

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
  int n(rand());

  if (n < 2 && n < 1)
    std::cout << "OK" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

compiling with

```
g++ -O3 -o test1 -fdump-tree-all test.cc
```

You'll get **a lot (!)** of files and among them:

test.cc.165t.optimized

```
;; Function int main() (main, funcdef_no=1013, decl_uid=21841, cgraph_uid=229) (executed once)

int main() ()
{
  int n;
  struct basic_ostream & _6;

  <bb 2>:
  n_4 = rand ();
  if (n_4 <= 0)
    goto <bb 3>;
  else
    goto <bb 4>;

  <bb 3>:
  _6 = std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> > (&cout, "OK");
  std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> > (_6);

  <bb 4>:
  return 0;

}
```

So you can check what optimizations gcc has performed:

```
if (n < 2 && n < 1)    //  optimized in if (n_4 <= 0) ...
```

Sometimes running the program in the gdb debugger and using the `disassemble /m` command to view the assembly mixed with the C / C++ code is a valid alternative.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Now I only have to learn how to read it, is there any help out there? Surely, people working in compilers (or, at least, early ones) must have developed something. See my answer for an online tool to produce the output.

Answer (score 3):

C++ is often constrained from optimizing large and-or expressions by its need to perform short-circuit evaluation.

If you're interested in how the compiler optimized your expression, reading the assembly is generally the best you can do.

If you're interested in what optimizations are *possible*, look into Karnaugh maps. I use those frequently to understand the latent patterns (and weaknesses!) in my logic. I think they're one of the most important tools programmers could learn from electrical engineers.

Comment: Karnaugh maps, and formal boolean algebra in general, are indeed very useful in general, but not for this kind of optimization, since facts like `n < 1 implies n < 2` are not statements of boolean algebra. Sure, you can introduce that knowledge and then draw a Karnaugh map to conclude that `p * p = p` but that's the sort of thing anyone with any skill whatsoever can spot instantly.

Comment: Yeh, that example was added after my answer. You're right, K-maps won't be of much use there.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you have a code fragment like:

```
bool b = true;
int i = 3;
if ((a || b) && ((i == 3) && b))
{
    printf("Yes!\n");
}
```

then with `-O0` you'll get exactly what you see here, but with `-O3` you'll get:

```
printf("Yes!\n");
```

All conditions and the if-statement itself are optimized away.

If you want to see what the compiler makes of it, try compiling with
`gcc -c -O0 -S test.cpp -o test.s`
respectively
`gcc -c -O3 -S test.cpp -o test.s`. That will generate assembly that you can compare.

Comment: Great answer! I was thinking of the exact same scenario: how can you be sure any optimization you see is "direct" or "indirect" -- as in this extreme case.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, I found an online tool to produce assembly code with different compilers.

http://gcc.godbolt.org/

I tried with the following code, and am still trying to understand the output.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
bool overlap = true;
int col1, col2, pdim, row1, row2;
bool condition;

col1 = rand();
col2 = rand();
row1 = rand();
row2 = rand();

std::cout << row2 << std::endl;

condition =((col1 < col2) && (col1 + pdim < col2))
    || ((col2 < col1) && (col2 + pdim < col1))
    || ((row1 < row2) && (row1 + pdim < row2))
    || ((row2 < row1) && (row2 + pdim < row1));

std::cout << condition << std::endl;
}
```